# Getting error while implementing thread android

Tags: android, multithreading

Am new in android .. am trying to implement thread in a android. But am getting error .. I googled and getting answer "AsyncTask", but truly i dont know how to implement

Error message

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

my code

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        @Override
                            public void run() {
                            try {
                                DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(test.this);
                                result=dbh.Verify(1);
                                if(result != ""){

                                    getData();
                                    progress.dismiss();

                                }
                                else{


                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
```

Comment: Use ASyncTask, that is the solution for you and it is very easy to implement there are bunch of samples out there.

Comment: You are not allowed to perform UI operation on non UI thread, so you need to do is `1. Create a handler and use hanlder.post()` method to update the UI or use `runOnUIthread`, search in google about the same

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to run in UI thread.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(test.this);
                            result=dbh.Verify(1);
                            if(result != ""){

                            getData();
                            progress.dismiss();

                        }
                        else{


                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: thank you..but if i want to call another database call in getData() function , what i can do ?

Comment: Then you have to use ASyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to create your handler in MainActivity and then pass it further. Like so:

```
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
}
```